# Why is this javascript injection attack not working?

Tags: javascript, code-injection, javascript-injection

I am trying to find the right way to harden my Javascript against code injection attacks.

So, I created what I thought would be a successful code injection:

```
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "hello <script> alert(0) <\/script> kuku";
```

Evaluating `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML` in debugger shows that it did go through:

```
"hello <script> alert(0) </script> kuku"
```

So how come there is no alert?

Comment: What do you mean, "*it did go through*"? The script seems clearly to no have been evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `.innerHTML` to content that includes `<script>` blocks will never cause the code embedded to be evaluated. That's just how `.innerHTML` works.

Comment: This answer is more direct and to the point compared to the one in the duplicate :D

Comment: Is it true for all browsers?

Comment: @ТаняТ.: It's true for IE, Safari, Chrome, Netscape, Firefox, Opera and Konqueror. Not sure about the rest. Is that enough for you?

Comment: Of course, NCSA Mosiac never implemented javascript so it's a non-issue for Mosiac.